# I want to fecth data from table by passing a foreign key of another table using sequalize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables in my DB. `Vendors`, `Products` and `Questions`. Questions table has a foreign key of products and products have a foreign key of vendors. How can I get all questions regarding a single vendor by passing a vendor id from front end? I want to show all questions on vendor dashboard posted to a particular vendor's products.
What I have tried right now is, get all product ids by vendor id and fetch questions then by those product ids. But it creates 2 queries with second query I have to map all product ids and query will run on every product id.

Is there a way I can do this in a single query by Sequalize?
Like I pass vendor id and then by vendor id it gets all products of that vendor and then get all questions that are on his/her products.

Thanks

Comment: This should just be two joins between the 3 tables. I don't know sequelize so I don't know its syntax for joins.

Comment: Can you please write mysql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple JOIN, translating it from SQL to sequelize is an exercise for you:

```
SELECT q.*, p.id AS product_id, p.name AS product_name
FROM Questions q 
JOIN Products p ON q.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.vendor_id = :vendor_id
```

You don't need to join with `Vendors` since you don't need to look up anything there -- you already know the vendor ID. If you had the vendor name instead of vendor ID, you'd need to add that join to get the corresponding ID.